# How to find the value of an unknown power, e.g $27^x = 81$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I find the value of $b$ in this problem $a^b = d$? I tried applying $b\sqrt{}$ to the both sides but I end up with an error.

Comment: Hint $27=3^3$ and $81=3^4$.

Comment: Do you know what a *logarithm* is?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Answer (score 7):

Write the equation as
$$
3^{3x}=3^4
$$
so that $3x=4$.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
$$27^x=81$$
And since $27=3^3$ and $81=3^4$, 
$$(3^3)^x=(3^4)$$
$$3^{3x}=3^4$$
Now do you see what to do?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is not any radical, but a logarithm (base 27).

When $a^x=b$, then $x=\log_a b$ where $\log_a$ denotes the logarithm with base $a$. Now, the base 27 logarithm is not usually found on calculators, so (if there wasn't a better way in this case) you would resort to a formula like
$$
\log_a b=\frac{\log_c a}{\log_c b}
$$
(and choose $c$ so your calculator implements that specific logarithm, $10$ or $e$ would be the most common choices).

In this case it's a lot better to realise that both $27$ and $81$ are powers of $3$, and use that to rewrite the equation as
$$
3^{3x}=3^4
$$
then you can find an exact solution.